# PyDAL audit trails outside of web app?

Tags: web2py, pydal

I am wondering if pydal supports audit trails when you are not using the webapp. My investigations [1][2] show that an `auth` module is needed for audit trails, but that appears to be something related to web2py not just pydal.

[1] https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/XpHugN9NBSI

[2] http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Record-versioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant functionality is built into pyDAL directly as described [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Record-versioning). For a given table, you can do:

```
db.mytable._enable_record_versioning()
```

The above method takes several optional arguments, as explained in the above linked documentation.

Note, if the table does not include an `is_active` field, there will be no record of deletions.